# Running a .js script inside a PowerShell script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, powershell

I am using a PowerShell script to install a local Mongo db on my customers machines. In order for this to work I am using a JavaScript batch to create a 'user profile' for the application. Here is the code I am using to call the JavaScript:

```
   Write-Host "Running user setup"
   if ($OS32bit)
   {
   & "$($location)\$($environment)\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongo.exe" localhost:$port $workingDirectory\InitMobileUser.js
   }
   else
   {
   & "$($location)\$($environment)\MongoDB\bin\mongo.exe" localhost:$port  $workingDirectory\InitMobileUser.js
   }
   Write-Host " "
   Write-Host "User Setup complete"

   # lets sleep to ensure the script has time to complete
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

What I am having an issue with is it seems like this is a "Fire and Forget" type call and the 10 seconds isn't enough of a wait time in about 1 out of 4 computers. I would like to have the PowerShell script dynamically wait for the Javascript to complete before continuing, similar to a c# await function.

Can this be done?
Thank you in advance for any help or links to other questions that answer this issue.

Comment: Are the line breaks in the correct places in your script?

Comment: hang on i will edit to put them right... sorry and thank you for noticing.

Comment: OK, so you are running `mongo.exe` with some parameters, one of which is a JavaScript script that presumably it knows how to parse. PowerShell blocks (i.e., waits for the command to complete) when you use the `&` operator in a script. If the command you launch does something asynchronously after you run it, there's no way for PowerShell to detect that. My suggestion would be to update the JavaScript code not to return until it's really finished. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: mongo.exe runs a process called 'mongod'. The last line of the javascript supposedly stops that process.

Comment: In that case the script needs to wait for the `mongod.exe` to end before it exits.

Comment: so the issue i am having is that the mongo.exe is started, then ended at the end of the JavaScript. so i am having a hard time getting the actual process name to put a "wait-process" onto. any hints there?

Comment: You could call it look for the process mongod to appear and loop a sleep command until mongod dies